# in Omnet++, c++ thinks variable is a function

Tags: c++, omnet++

I am using Omnet++ and writing the C++ code. I have the following declaration in my ned file:

```
channel Link extends ned.DatarateChannel
{
    datarate = 16Gbps; // 32 lines of 2ns clock
    delay = 0us;
}
```

Inside my module's .cc file, I am writing the following function:

```
void InPortAsync::getErrorTimeout(int sx, int sy, int rx, int ry, int dx, int dy, int &routerType, simtime_t &timeout)
{   // find the flight time for packet from this node to the next joint node = TTL in queue
    int dir0 =-1;
    int dir1 =-1;
    int temprx = -1;
    int tempry = -1;
    int outPort = -1;
    int destRouterType, destTimeout;
    Link* temp_Channel;
    ...
}
```

It is clear I am declaring a pointer to a Link object named temp_Channel. However, the compiler returns the following error:
**'temp_Channel' was not declared in this scope**

Why doesn't GCC understand my declaration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you forget to include the proper header for `Link`? Are you sure the error comes from the line you are showing us and not another one?

Comment: Is it really C++?

Comment: I've never used Omnet, but I think the ned file must be used to generate a .h file that contains the definition of Link. Does such a file exist? Have you included it? Still strange that GCC chokes on `temp_Channel` rather than on `Link`, though.

Comment: Where does it "return" that error?

Comment: @FabioTurati: It probably chokes on both and the OP is ignoring all but the last few lines.

Comment: You are declaring it inside getErrorTimeout() member function. The error probably occurs within another function.

Comment: 1. The error is on the line defining the Link* object.

Comment: 2. I did not prepare a header since I assumed I am accessing a well-defined module that was defined in Omnet++. According to the answer it is not well-defined, but I still need to access the link's delay from the c++ code...

Answer (score 4):

Declaring the `Link` channel in a NED file has nothing to do with the C++ code. It will NOT generate any headers, or C++ classes that you can include in your code. In fact NED files are processed only at runtime and not at compile time.

Comment: I need to access attributes of this version of DatarateChannel in a module linked to it, how do I do it?

Comment: I found out how - I used a reference to the father class of Link - `DatarateChannel` through the c class `cDatarateChannel`. I still don't understand how to refer to the type of Link itself, or if it even exists in c++.

Comment: Extending the `DatarateChannel` NED type does *not* create a new C++ class. The C++ class behind the `Link` NED type is still `cDatarateChannel`. You can see this as `Link` inherits the behavior (i.e. C++ implementation) from `cDatarateChannel`. If you want to introduce also new behavior, you should use the `@class(MyNewClass)` property to specify which C++ class should be used to define the behavior of the NED type.